# Burgers' equation with triangular initial data

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

The problem is:

> Consider Burgers' equation,
>   $$u_t +uu_x = 0 $$ 
>   $$ u(x,0) = f(x) $$
>   where
>   $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 - |x-2| &\mbox{if}\,\, 1\leq x \leq3, \\ 0 &\mbox{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
>   a) What is the first time $t_0$ where a shock forms?
>
> b) Sketch solution at time $t=2$.
>
> c) What is the shock velocity?

I'm a bit confused where to start, any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! We would be glad to help out. However, it would help us to hear any additional information regarding the problem. What have you learned up to this point, what you have tried so far, etc. We will usually give more help when it is clear that a lot of effort has gone into trying to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic methodology that you can apply and work out the details for specific  initial data.

You can use the method of characteristics to find an implicit solution.

The characteristics are determined by the IVP

$$\frac{dX}{dt}= u(X(t),t),\\X(0) = x_0.$$

If $u$ is differentiable , we have

$$\frac{d}{dt}u[X(t),t]= u_t(X(t),t) + u_x(X(t),t)\frac{dX}{dt}=u_t(X(t),t) + u(X(t),t)u_x(X(t),t)=0.$$

Hence, along a characteristic curve $u(X(t),t)$ is constant

$$u(X(t),t)= u(X(0),0)=f(x_0).$$

Solving for $X(t)$ we obtain

$$X(t) = x_0 + f(x_0)t.$$

Therefore, $u(x,t)=f(x_0)$ at a specific point $(x,t) $with $t > 0$ -- where $x_0$ is the solution to $x_0 = x - f(x_0)t$.

If two characteristics cross, then the solution becomes multi-valued.  This can be interpreted as the formation of a discontinuity or shock. The first time this happens is determined is follows.

Consider two characteristics initiated at points $(y,0)$ and $(y + \delta,0)$, respectively. If they intersect at time $t$ then

$$y + f(y)t = y + \delta + f(y + \delta)t$$

and

$$t = \frac{\delta}{f(y)-f(y+\delta)}$$

The earliest possible time for the formation of a shock is then given by

$$t_s = \inf_{y} \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 0} \frac{\delta}{f(y)-f(y+\delta)}=\inf_{y}\frac{-1}{f'(y)}.$$

Suppose a shock is located at position $x_S(t)$ with $u(x,t) = u_L$ if $-\delta < x < x_S(t)$ and $u(x,t) = u_R$ if $\delta >x > x_S(t).$

Then,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} u(x,t) \, dx = \int_{-\delta}^{\delta} u_t \, dx = -\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} uu_x \, dx \\= -\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac1{2}u^2\right) \, dx = \frac1{2}(u_L^2-u_R^2).$$

Also,

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\delta}^{\delta} u(x,t) \, dx =\frac{d}{dt}\left[u_R(\delta-x_s)+u_L(x_s+\delta)\right]=\frac{dx_S}{dt}(u_L-u_R).$$

Hence,

$$\frac{dx_S}{dt}(u_L-u_R)=\frac1{2}(u_L^2-u_R^2),$$

and the shock propagates at a speed given by

$$\frac{dx_S}{dt} = \frac1{2}(u_L + u_R).$$

Comment: Right I believe it forms when t = 1 but how do I solve for shock velocity?

Comment: Can you clarify the initial condition. You wrote $x = 1,2,3$. Perhaps it is piecewise linear on $[1,2]$ and $[2,3]$.

Comment: I meant to say x is element of 1-3. I didn't know how to write that.

Comment: That would be $x \in [1,3]$.  I added shock speed above.  In your case, the initial profile is a triangle with base from $x=1$ to $x=3$ and a height of $1$ at $x=2$.  The shock forms at $t=1$ and propagates with speed $v_s = (1+0)/2 = 1/2$.

Comment: IS the shock velocity top minus bottom

Comment: its the mean of the u value to the left and the right $(u_L + u_R)/2$

Answer (score 3):

Let us complete the answer by @RRL.

a) The breaking time is $$t_b = \frac{-1}{\inf f'} = 1$$

b-c) This is illustrated on a sketch of the characteristic curves in the $x$-$t$ plane:

[image: characteristics]

On both sides of the shock, the solution at $t>1$ is deduced from the method of characteristics $u = f(x-ut)$. Hence, $u$ is equal to $\frac{x-1}{1+t}$ or zero on each side of the shock. To compute, the shock trajectory $x_s(t)$ with the shock velocity $\dot x_s(t)$, we apply the Rankine-Hugoniot condition
$$
\dot{x}_s(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{x_s(t)-1}{1+t} + 0\right) ,\qquad x_s(1) = 3 ,
$$
which gives $x_s(t) = 1 + \sqrt{2 (1+t)}$ and $\dot x_s(t) = \sqrt{2(1+t)}^{-1}$. At $t> 1$, the solution is
$$u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&0 &&\text{if}\quad x<1 \quad\text{or}\quad x > 1 + \sqrt{2 (1+t)} \\
&\frac{x-1}{1+t} &&\text{if}\quad 1\leq x < 1 + \sqrt{2 (1+t)} 
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Comment: @RRL the shock speed $\dot x_s$ is equal to $1/2$ at the breaking time $t=1$, but it decreases in time afterwards.