# Inverted Triangle Burgers' Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

I wish to solve the so-called Burgers' equation $u_t+uu_x=0$ with the initial data
$$u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
1 & x<-1\\
-x & -1\leq x\leq 0\\
x & 0\leq x\leq 1\\
1 & x>1
\end{cases}$$

I'm having trouble drawing the characteristic lines, but I know that the slope of the initial data (wrt t) corresponds to the value of the solution. Furthermore, I also see that there should be a shock formation at $t=-1$ (I think?)

Thank help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1018077/418542), the breaking time where a shock wave forms is
$$
t_b= \frac{-1}{\inf u_x(x,0)} = 1 \, .
$$
The base characteristics represented below in the $x$-$t$ plane illustrate this feature:

[image: characteristics]